# ERROR: syntax error at or near "psycopg2"

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am trying to query my PostgreSQL database to retrieve my table. i keep falling into this error of **Psycopg2**

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = pyscopg2.connect(database='wildlife', user='postgres', password='P@$$w0rd', host='localhost' port='5432')
    print "successfully connected to database"

except:
    print "connection Failure"

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT ID,NAME,LIVES,WEIGHT,LEGS,CLASS,NUMBER,CATEGORY FROM CAGE";)
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print "ID = ", row[0]
    print "NAME = ", row[1]
    print "LIVES = ", row[2], "\n"

conn.close()
```

and the error

```
Error executing SQL statement. ERROR: syntax error at or near "psycopg2"
```

Position: 8 - Connection: phase1: 275ms

Comment: Are you indenting correctly for your `try` and `except` blocks or did you just paste it incorrectly in your question?

Comment: well the indent does not matter, bcause even when i change the indent, same error

Comment: Indent certainly matters when it comes to valid code. Update your question with the proper indents otherwise that is the first thing others will look to as an issue.

Comment: Also, was is the output (if anything) - does it print `"successfully connected to database"`, `"connection Failure"` or does it only show the error message?

Comment: no, it does not print anything. only shows the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line contains a typo:

`conn = pyscopg2.connect(...`

It should be:

`conn = psycopg2.connect(`

The "y" and "s" were transposed.

Comment: Thanks, though when you look through all the script. could you see any other errors, with **SELECT**

Comment: The `SELECT` statement seems fine.